# Javascript: prevent space key scrolling in specify div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a textarea inside a div. The textarea taller than div but not vertical scroll-able. Instead, the div vertical scroll-able. However, when I disable the textarea by javascript and blur() all of them, the space keystroke still affect the div as scroll page down. I tried many way to get rid of this but no luck. Here's my code:

```css
#container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 200px;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  word-wrap: off;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <textarea>{...}</textarea>
</div>
```

The height of textarea is actually automatic adjusted by javascript when number of lines increase. So it's not a static number. Is that any way to prevent the parent div respond to the space key event? Thanks!

Comment: if blur. keycode for space bar, preventdefault()

Answer (score 9):

This should do the trick.  Probably more checks here than necessary but I prefer to err on the side of caution.

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (charCode === 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

You could also do this with jQuery if that's your thing:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32)
        return false;
});
```

In both of these examples you could change `document`/`window` to be your element or whatever element you want to disable spacebar on.